# Conflict when saving a list item

Tags: list, error, save

I'm using a workflow to clone an item.

When you modify and save a get a conflict error values ​​item. 
No users have this open item. Also has no code that update() in this item.
The only thing I have is a workflow that runs when an item is created.
But have disabled this flow and keep getting the error.

Anyone have any idea what might cause this error?

I am using SharePoint 2013